# Pran Pratishta 's life scale in Deity's idol or statue and Scriptures of Pran Pratishta mantras

Tags: idols, pranapratishtha

Can anyone let me know what is the life scale of Pran in Deity's Vigraha and where the Pran Pratishta Mantras are mentioned in religious Scriptures?

Comment: I can answer for Yantras. Or the period for which the Prana stays in the Yantras after the Pranaprathishtha.

Comment: @Rickross ok, so Pran is god's energy right? So yantras and statue have different time scale?

Comment: Yes Prana is the life-force of God.. In case of Yantras the lifespans depend on the material the Yantra is made of.. So for gold made Yantra it is something and for copper made something else.. For idols I don't really know.

Comment: @Rickross ohh ok.. actually I want to know the time scale in statue and the scripture name in which mantra is mentioned